# PHP loading XML stream causes MySQL INSERT INTO table to no longer work

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I've been working on this single problem all day and I can not make light of it, so thought I'd ask the seasoned professionals!

Essentially, if I remove the XML connecting lines (first four at the top), my "INSERT INTO" statements work (using static values), if I don't remove them I get no error message from MySQL / PHP.... they simply do not work.

The database is all set to accept nulls (temporarily) on all fields, and they're all VARCHAR for now... just until I can figure out what is going on.

The XML feed seems to connect without a problem, as the page takes ages to load and when I ECHO the output, all the correct values are coming in.

The biggest thing to note is that when I echo the INSERT INTO command, then copy and paste it into PHP My Admin... the actual insert line works perfectly fine... just when the XML is turned on; it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why I can not seem to use:

```
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query);
```

After an XML feed has been connected to?

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = "https://thedatastream.xml";
$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($xml->row as $item) {

  $partNumber = strval(escape($item->PartNumber));
  $partName = strval(escape($item->Name));
  $partBrand = strval(escape($item->Manufacturer));
  $partCategory = strval(escape($item->CategoryName));
  $partGroup = strval(escape($item->Group));
  $partQty = intval(escape($item->Quantity));
  $partCostEx = floatval(escape($item->PriceCostEx));
  $partRetailEx = floatval(escape($item->PriceRetailEx));
  $partDesc = strval(escape($item->Description));
  $partHTMLDesc = strval(escape($item->HTMLDescription));
  $partImg = strval($item->image_large);
  $partPDF = strval($item->PDFURL);
  $partUpdated = strval(escape($item->StockRecordUpdated));
  $partETA = strval($item->ETADate);
  $partETAStatus = strval($item->ETAStatus);

  $query15 = "INSERT INTO `downloadTbl` (`partNumber`, `partName`, `Manufacturer`, `CategoryName`, `Group`, `Unit`, `PriceCostEx`, `PriceRetailEx`, `Description`, `HTMLDescription`, `image_large`, `PDFURL`, `StockRecordUpdated`, `ETADate`, `ETAStatus`) VALUES ('".$partNumber."', '".$partName."', '".$partBrand."', '".$partCategory."', '".$partGroup."', '".$partQty."', '".$partCostEx."', '".$partRetailEx."', '".$partDesc."', '".$partHTMLDesc."', '".$partImg."', '".$partPDF."', '".$partUpdated."', '".$partETA."', '".$partETAStatus."')";
  $result15 = mysqli_query($cxn, $query15);
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Why do you overwrite `$query15` in `foreach()` loop

Comment: try to format your question :)

Comment: Are you aware that you're executing the insert query only once? Regardless of how many entries in the XML are?

Comment: I've updated the code, I had been playing with various ways to get it working, hence the un-needed count++; and the $query15 being over written everytime... that said, it still doesn't answer why I can not complete MySQL transactions (INSERT INTO) from within the XML loop... Any good ideas? Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you, although I am mostly stuck by the fact that the INSERT wont function at all :s

Comment: A little more light to add to it... is the error that PHP is reporting. It's quite a large XML feed, so maybe something to do with it timing out or something???

Notice: MySQL server has gone away in /home/jus33386/public_html/cgi-bin/stock.php on line 82

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer!

The downloading of the XML file was causing a time out of the database connection,

I simply created a second connection after the XML file completed downloading and used that for the INSERT statements.

```
$cxn2 = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
```

I think you could just re-connect the first database connection, instead of making a second one.

Thank you to everyone who helped to resolve this problem.